Trying to set up a data acquisition system--have some questions
I'm setting up a data acquisition system for some load cell, pressure ducer, and thermocouple inputs. Currently looking at the LabJack T7 for my ADC and INA125 for my load cell amp. PTs are self-amplified and the LabJack has TC support.
I want to set up several sensors, and given that I've only got 7 differential inputs available to me, I wanted to feed the load cell and PT data using a single-ended configuration so I can get more sensors wired up.
I am completely unfamiliar with data acquisition and electronics in general so have some basic questions.
Can the INA125 be configured for a single ended input? Is it as easy as shorting the outputs, or just using a common ground across all sensors and feeding the positive output to the LabJack?
Can this same idea be applied to thermocouples? The LabJack has TC support, but to get more sensor inputs could I possibly ground them all out with the PTs and load cells?
Thanks!!
